# accept a socket in one thread and write data in different thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, networking

Is it legal to accept and read from TCP socket in one thread and write data in same socket in another thread on Linux?

```
Example:
// thread #1
// ...
int sock = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen));
// .. read from socket sock

#thread #2
// ...
int n = send(sock, buffer, 1024);
// ...
```

it is legal or undefined behaviour?

Comment: It's fine, if a bit overkill for inter thread communication.

Comment: Difficult to do. How does the writing thread know about the `sock`, the accepted socket? In general the accepting thread should not do any I/O with the accepted sockets, otherwise that I/O can block and hold up subsequent connect attempts. Every accepted socket should have its I/O done in a new thread.

Comment: @Shawn what you mean under overkill?

Comment: @user207421 There are no locks because non-blocking sockets are used. The writing thread checks the queue and then know about the accepted socket if the queue is not empty

Comment: Compared to pipes (one way), anonymous unix domain sockets created with `socketpair()` (two way), thread safe message queues, etc...